# Python who to write to file encoding 'latin-1'

Tags: python, encoding, latin1

I know there are many questions out there already concerning encoding/decoding. But this is driving me nuts and I'm in desperate need of some help.

I read in a file converting the lines to `unicode`

```
line = unicode(line,'latin-1')
```

Then, I do some mutations and try to write the contents back to a file, encoding the string like this

```
o_str = '%s,%s' % (new_sname, loc )
w_out.write(o_str.encode('latin-1'))
```

The file contains for instance the city name 'Genève' which is `u'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'` as unicode. Encoding it as 'Latin-1'

```
gue = gu.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

gives me on the console

```
>>> print gue
Genève
```

But in file my file it still is 'GenÃ¨ve'. Can somebody point me to what I am missing?

Comment: The editor which you use, might use a different encoding to display the string.

Comment: You mean the text editor? No, I check that already.

Comment: `u'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'` is **not** correct unicode. That is UTF-8 data instead, decoded from latin-1.

Comment: @thefourtheye Regardless of which encoding the editor uses, the letter è should still only look like a single letter if it was correctly encoded with latin-1. Which leads me to the conclusion that the Python script encodes with a wide-character encoding like UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are decoding UTF-8 data as Latin 1, use the correct codec instead:

```
>>> 'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'.decode('latin1')
u'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'
>>> print 'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'.decode('latin1')
GenÃ¨ve
>>> 'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'.decode('utf8')
u'Gen\xe8ve'
>>> print 'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'.decode('utf8')
Genève
```

The correct Unicode codepoint for the `è` letter is `U+00E8`, represented by `\u00e8` or `\xe8` in a Python Unicode literal, and the hex bytes C3A8 in UTF-8. Misintepreting C3 A8 leads to two unicode characters `Ã` and `¨`, which you then write back to your file as C3 and A8 again because Latin1 maps one-on-one with Unicode.

Comment: I get it. But I bet when I will look at it tomorrow I'll be confused again;-)

Comment: OT: the Careers 2.0 link in your profile is a 404 for me because it leads to the edit view of your profile. Use your public URL instead. :-)